# Random NullReferenceException on Timer.Stop

Tags: c#

I have a System.Timers.Timer that randomly throws a NullReferenceException when I call the Stop() method.  This probably occurs probably about 4 times a work day.  I've seen the problem repeated on multiple computers.

```
void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if (myTimer != null) //trying to stop the exception here
  {
    myTimer.Stop(); //Null Reference Exception occurs here

    DoStuff();

    myTimer.Start();
  }
}
```

The stack looks like this:

[image: stack]

The weirdest part is that I can immediately start the program again from the position of the exception with no problems.

Comment: Is this called from multiple threads?

Comment: Have you somewhere a `myTimer.Dispose()`?

Comment: presumably somewhere you must be either: a) calling `myTimer.Dispose()` or b) setting `myTimer = null` or c) closing/destroying/disposing the class that holds the reference to `myTimer`

Comment: Is this event attached to multiple timers?

Comment: @DStanley It's a timer, it inherently involves multiple threads.

Comment: @DStanley: The class is created multiple times possibly from different threads.

Comment: No Dispose().  I'll see if it's possible that the class it's in is being destroyed.  However I'd assume I couldn't carry on immediately if that was the case.

Comment: the timer is private and NOT static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  lock(this) {
  if (myTimer != null) //trying to stop the exception here
  {
    myTimer.Stop(); //Null Reference Exception occurs here

    DoStuff();

    myTimer.Start();
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  It's likely to be several hours before another error might occur.

Comment: This will work if you have ho other places where you assigning `null` to `myTimer`. Your problem is that it changes between check and use. This can be done only from parallel thread. If it is so, than `lock` will protect. If you have multiple places which can change `myTimer` then protect them all with `lock(<the_same_and_only_instance>)`

Comment: Seems to have worked, thanks!  Now to just figure out why multiple threads are getting in there and why it's null...

Comment: Open `Threads` window in debugger (`Debug->Windows->Threads`). You will see current thread when stop on breakpoint.